# Can't install mongodb via 10gen.repo on Amazon 64bit AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, yum, installation, mongodb

Following the instructions here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CentOS+and+Fedora+Packages

Can't really decipher what I should be doing...broke down and just got the linux binary but I want yum control...

```
$ cat /etc/yum.repos.d/10gen-mongodb.repo

[10gen]
name=10gen Repository
baseurl=http://downloads.mongodb.org/distros/centos/5.4/os/x86_64/
gpgcheck=0

$ sudo yum install mongo-stable mongo-stable-server

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Setting up Install Process
No package mongo-stable available.
No package mongo-stable-server available.
```

Also tried:

```
baseurl=http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/x86_64
```

Are these packages just no longer available at these locations? Not sure if it's a technicality wrt redhat vs centos. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use baseurl `http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/x86_64` for 64-bit system, and `http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/i686` for 32-bit system. New packages name: mongo-10gen and mongo-10gen-server. For install:

```
 # yum install mongo-10gen-server mongo-10gen
```